If a kohen donates sperm to a convert or divorcee, is the child a kohen
According to Halacha, If a Kohen decides to donate sperm to a convert or divorcee, is the  child conceived through that a Kohen or no?
The reason I ask is become some Poskim, such as R Moshe Feinstein, permit IVF for otherwise forbidden relationships. Under that logic does the Kohen status here carry on (because what creates the chalal status of a Kohen’s baby with a convert or divorcee is the forbidden sex, not them both being parents)?

I would first ask if a kohen donates to a regular woman is the child a kohen. Only if the answer is yes would your question be relevant. I was told that my question is a matter of doubt.

Just to clarify, your premise is that the reason a Kohen who has a child with a convert or a divorcee has a non-Kohen child (Chalal) is because the intimacy is forbidden, so then if there's a child without intimacy (IVF), the child would be a Kohen? Or as you asking what's the mechanism which creates a Chalal? The forbidden union? Or the forbidden intimacy?

So why not ask more generally: "What creates a Chalal, the forbidden union, or the forbidden intimacy?"

The Rabbi responding below leans toward considering the boy a kohen
https://din.org.il/2015/11/16/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%AA-%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%A2-%D7%9E%D7%9B/
